# Create a hashmap with the names of the fields in the class as the key, and the values of those fields as the values of the map

Tags: java, class, reflection

Let's say you have a class: SomeClass with fields a=10, b=20, and c=30, where instanceOfSomeClass.getA()==10. I want a map like this

```
{
    a:10
    b:20
    c:30
}
```

I tried this, but got Class can not access a member of class with modifiers "private static final", but I also can't modify this class to not have private static final:

```
      Field[] fields = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
      for (Field f : fields) {
        map.put(f.toString(), f.get(instanceOfSomeClass).toString());
      }
```

Any ideas on how to make this hashmap?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  `private static final` fields _aren't_ associated with `instanceOfSomeClass`, so why do you want them?

Comment: I don't, I suppose
Is it possible to check if a field is private static final field is private static final before attempting to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

When you're looping through the `Field` objects, use `Field.getModifiers()` to determine each field's accessibility (public, private, static, etc).

As mentioned in the JavaDoc for `Field.getModifiers()`, use the class `Modifier` (which has static methods such as `isFinal()`, `isPrivate()`, etc) to "decode" the int value you get from `getModifiers()`.

For example (untested pseudo-code):

```java
for (Field f : fields) {
    int modifiers = f.getModifiers();
    if (Modifier.isStatic(modifiers)) {  // Skip static fields, for example
        continue;
    }

    map.put(f.toString(), f.get(instanceOfSomeClass).toString());
}
```

Comment: And use `field.setAccessible(true)` to override access restrictions.

Comment: When you want to *skip* static fields, rather than terminating the loop on the first occurrence, wouldn’t it make more sense to use `continue;` instead of `break;`? And I suppose `f.toString()` should rather be `f.getName()`…

Comment: Yikes, good catch, @Holger. Fixed. At least I labeled it as "untested pseudo-code") :-)

Answer (score -1):

**I guess this is your expected solution:**

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

class SomeClass {
    public static int a = 10;
    public static int b = 20;
    public static int c = 40;
}

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try{
            SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
            
            Field[] fields = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
        
            for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

                // Getting the field's name and its value
                Object value = fields[i].get(sc);
                Object fieldName = fields[i].getName();

                // System.out.println("Field = " + fields[i].getName() + " Value = " + value + "\n");

                // Adding value into the HashMap
                map.put(fieldName.toString(), value.toString());
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        // Iterating through the HashMap
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + e.getKey() + " Value: " + e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

***Output**:*

```
Key: a Value: 10
Key: b Value: 20
Key: c Value: 40
```